# thinking-sphinx + REXML error in rails 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, full-text-search, thinking-sphinx, rexml

I'm trying to get `sphinx` running via `thinking-sphinx`, everything works fine until I go to the search page

I have the following model

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
 define_index do
  indexes [lastname, firstname]
 end
end
```

and In my application controller I have include (after some web  search)

```
include REXML
```

But when I go to students controller index action

```
def index
    @students = Student.search params[:search]
end
```

i'm getting the following error

```
undefined method `default_external' for REXML::Encoding:Module
```

any idea on what is happening?

my env is as follows

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.10
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2011-12-28 patchlevel 357) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/sameera/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/sameera/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p357/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/sameera/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/sameera/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357
     - /home/sameera/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/


 Linux

 thinking-sphinx-1.4.11
```

rails 2.3.8

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what the issue is exactly, but I think I've heard of others having issues combining Thinking Sphinx with REXML. What happens if you don't use/load REXML?

Comment: Hi @pat, thanks for the answer, actually with out using load REXML also I'm getting the same error (So probably it has nothing to do with this error, I just tried it because in web there are some recomandations to use like that way)

Comment: That'd be odd, because the error references REXML... are you still loading REXML in your app, even though it's not in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Sphinx are you trying to setup? sphinx 2 works only with Rails 3 http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/rails3.html

Comment: Not quite - thinking-sphinx 2.x is for Rails 3, but any recent thinking-sphinx 1.x release will support up to Sphinx 2.0.3 (and Sphinx 2.0.4 is committed, just not in a gem release yet).

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I'm following this screen cast http://railscasts.com/episodes/120-thinking-sphinx?autoplay=true, and My project runs in rails 2.3.8 with thinking-sphinx-1.4.11

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by pat on the [Riddle Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/thinking-sphinx/fEn5lA1v7Ig), not including REXML, but just requiring it fix the issue.